# NHibernate не распознает совместный запрос

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Для работы с MS SQL используется NHibernate. Для создания запроса используется метод CreateQuery:

```cs
string query = $@"INSERT INTO [{table_name}] ([p1], [p2]) VALUES (:p1_val, :p2_val)";

Session.CreateQuery(query)
    .SetParameter("p1_val", p1_val)
    .SetParameter("p2_val", p2_val)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

При выполнении возвращается следующая ошибка:

```
A recognition error occurred. near line 1, column 12
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse()
   at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
<...>
```

Исполняемая строка кода (из описания исключения):

```
INSERTINTO[<table_name>]([p1],[p2])VALUES(:p1_val,:p2_val)
```

Конфиг:

```xml
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.connection_string"><connection_string></property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">500</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Похоже, что по какой-то причине в запросе удаляются пробелы. Однако до последнего момента этот код работал корректно. В чем может быть причина этого? Я просто в замешательстве.

Comment: Всё ещё актуально.